# I am trying to run query but i am not able to get right output and i am getting this error

Tags: mysql, sql, database

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7  0.016 sec

```
DELIMITER $$

create trigger postponement
 BEFORE insert
 on flight 
for each row BEGIN
IF NEW.Time_of_depart = Flight.Time_of_depart
THEN
SELECT ADDTIME(EW.Time_of_depart, "00:30:00");
END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: What you want the trigger to do isn't clear.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: i have a flight table with time of departure and date of departure columns for the flights , and i'm trying to delay every new insertion for the the new flights 30 mins only if there's another flight have the same time and date for the departure . Thank you

Comment: `IF NEW.Time_of_depart = Flight.Time_of_depart` What do you think, which record from the `Flight` table will be taken for comparison? You must SELECT some definite record from this table using some field from NEW.

Comment: It start by the first  mention of flight.Time_of_depart  You have to select the data prior comparision. The next is when you want to add time to NEW.Time_of_depart it must be SET NEW.Time_of_depart =  ADDTIME(NEW.Time_of_depart, "00:30:00");